# Add and delete entities from a JSP Form client side

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I create a dynamic form based on database elements using SpringMVC. This form is used to declare login and passwords. The JSP looks like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${formProperty.formUsers}" var="user" varStatus="status">
    <ul>
        <li class="liDelUser">
            <form:hidden path="formUsers[${status.index}].id"/>
            <t:genericButton id="btnDelUser" label="" iconclass="icons icon_delete" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <form:label path="formUsers[${status.index}].username">Login</form:label>
            <form:input path="formUsers[${status.index}].username" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <form:label path="formUsers[${status.index}].password">Password</form:label>
            <form:password path="formUsers[${status.index}].password" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</c:forEach>
<t:genericButton id="btnAddUser" label="Add user" iconclass="icons icon_add" />
```

To delete a user, I can find the parent UL and remove it...

but how can I add a new user to the Form using JQuery?

Comment: You can find the parent UL and apply `.insertAfter(...)` JQuery function. However, it's not really good to hack html using this approach. Use AngularJS for such operations, it has been designed specially for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to do this by using empty form objects:

- Send the list and append an empty form at the end of this list. Hide the form with an empty ID then show it when the user clicks *ADD*. With this way, you can add only one entry per POST.

or

- Send the list. When the user clicks *ADD*, send an AJAX GET to download an empty form and append it to your list. This is slightly slower but is more flexible. You can cache the empty form in memory for later reuse.